# Will Flask ever stop detecting changes?

Tags: python, flask

I made a new anaconda installation and happily fired up a Flask program but was promptly overwhelmed. Hundreds and thousands of "detected change in .... reloading".  That was three days ago. by yesterday it seemed to have calmed down a bit and would believe it was detecting a change about once every minute. It has kept up that rate since. What I assume is happening is that it is slowly but surely making some kind of map of my python environment.

Does this ever end? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Thanks, Tunneller

Comment: Did you install Flask to your root or to a virtualenv?

Comment: to base environment. It's basically going through every package installed

Comment: This was the most recent. Detected change in 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\cytoolz-0.11.0-py38he774522_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\cytoolz\\curried\\__pycache__\\exceptions.cpython-38.pyc', reloading

Comment: In the future, just create a virtual environment and keep it isolated. Probably explains why you’re getting all these notifications.

Comment: It stopped a few days after I posted the question. I think it was related to being a new anaconda installation that was confusing the flask app to thinking everything needed updating. I do use virtual environment when I have something "odd" to test. But I want Flask in my base environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `debug=False` in the run statement. For example:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

This will stop the flask app from detecting changes to files it is using and updating itself.